Raster Calculator issue for Multi Band Raster File in QGIS
I am using raster calculator in QGIS to filter out the rangeland area of ESA LULC raster file for region of Interest.
The raster file has three bands (RGB)
Earlier, I performed the task in ArcGIS and got results in same way.
Raster Calculator Expression: ESA==12 (12 represent rangeland area)
This produces a binary output file map where 1 represents the filtered area and 0 remaining area.
However, in QGIS the raster calculator shows the bands in different manner eg. ESA@1, ESA@2 etc..
I am not getting any value in 1 and all values are in 0.
I have the following queries:

Does the QGIS and ArcGIS Pro raster calculator process the multiband raster files in same way?
The QGIS raster file shows ESA@1 only which doesn't give desired results. Should I use ESA@2 and ESA@3 which are other bands also? How to use the same?

Please let me know how to resolve the issue.

Welcome to GIS SE. Please only ask one question at a time. Can you better describe your data? You seem to imply colour coding with the mention of RGB, while your expression looks into a LULC code. What information is actually contained in your three bands?
